# Examples of applications of category theory to chemistry

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, applications, chemistry

What is some simple application of category theory to chemistry, namely, something that is much easier to do in chemistry with category theory than without. It does not need to be bleeding edge, or to have originated with category theory, but just an example demonstrating the possible use of category theory in chemistry. It should be at an elementary level both chemically and categorically if possible.

Comment: Are there any applications to chemistry?

Comment: Well, I remember there being a category with chemicals as objects and reactions as morphisms.

Answer (score 2):

[Petri nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net)  model networks and distributed systems, but also chemical reactions. They can be seen as symmetric monoidal categories.

> The Azimuth Project, [Petri net](http://www.azimuthproject.org/azimuth/show/Petri+net)

[V. Sassone](http://www.ecs.soton.ac.uk/people/vs/publications) has several publications about this connection between Petri nets and category theory.